# Varnish 4.0.1 can't start on CentOS 7 - selinux issue

Tags: linux, centos, varnish, selinux

I have installed with yum varnish-4.0.1 on CentOS 7.
If selinux is enforced, then varnish can't start - in /var/log/audit/audit.log has info

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1412255357.638:531): avc:  denied  { fowner } for  pid=4441 comm="varnishd" capability=3  scontext=system_u:system_r:varnishd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:varnishd_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1412255357.638:531): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=no exit=-1 a0=7fff0bb219f0 a1=1ed a2=0 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=4441 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="varnishd" exe="/usr/sbin/varnishd" subj=system_u:system_r:varnishd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1412255357.659:532): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="varnish" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
```

If selinux disabled with setenforce 0, then varnishd starts correctly.

How to fix this selinux issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was fixed in Fedora (at least the bug was closed). Opening a bug at bugzilla.redhat.com referencing that bug might be more productive than posting here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1083111

Answer (score -3):

you definitely want to set it to `permissive` as it is also another option to try

Comment: No, that's definetly _not_ what you want to do, as this is basically disabling SELinux the same way `setenforce 0` does. What one wants to do is to debug the SELinux configuration using `permissive` mode.